# while passing string to date it showing error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

```
String Insert_data= "Insert into online_table(online_id,online_email,to_char(online_Date,'dd-mom-yy') online_date "+ 
                    "values(?,?,?)";
```

I am trying to change insert data from the Postman. In online_date to be date format in the database, but in Java entity file I keep the online_date as the String format. I'm trying to convert String to Date format while inserting record in database.

Comment: Does `Insert into online_table(online_id,online_email,online_Date+ values(?,?,to_char(?,'dd-mom-yy'));` work?

Comment: Actually, you are using Spring-boot then why can't you use Spring JPA to save the entity, DRY(Don't repeat yourself) if there is an existing utility to serve the purpose at ease until there is no another way to do it

Comment: 1) What you showed us is not valid (compilable) Java.  So clearly this is not your real code.  2) Try printing out what the query string expands to.  Then look at it carefully and compare it with the Oracle SQL syntax, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to convert String to Date format while inserting record in
> database.

Then you should be using TO_DATE, not TO_CHAR.

TO_CHAR takes a DATE as input and returns a VARCHAR2.
TO_DATE takes a STRING as input and returns an oracle DATE.  And an oracle DATE is a binary structure, not in human readable format.

And please use 4-digit years.  I spent too much time in 1998-1999 remediating the Y2K problem, just to see it recreated 20+ years later.